# How do I test this stateless component with enzyme and jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

*DisplayTypes.tsx*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '../../Shared/Checkbox/Checkbox';

const displayTypes = ({
  appTypes,
  changed,
  userAssignedApplicatorTypes
}: any) => {
  return appTypes.map((applicatorType: any) => {
    let isChecked = userAssignedApplicatorTypes.find(
        (application: any) => 
           application.applicatorTypeName === applicatorType.name
    );
    return (
        <Checkbox
            id={applicatorType.id}
            key={applicatorType.id}
            changed={changed.bind(null, applicatorType.name)}
            element={applicatorType.name}
            isChecked={isChecked}
        />
    );
  });
};

export default displayTypes;
```

Here, I am displaying a Checkbox for every value in 'appTypes' and passing 'isChecked' value to each Checkbox.

The test coverage shows these lines are not covered. I want to test this part with enzyme and jest:

```
    let isChecked = userAssignedApplicatorTypes.find(
        (application: any) =>
            application.applicatorTypeName === applicatorType.name
    );
```

How do I do this?

Comment: `isChecked` is passed in as a prop, then reassigned from the `.find()` result. Probably want to address this (though I doubt it's related to the question).

Answer (score 1):

When you describe checking the `isChecked` condition, I assume you're verifying based on how it binds to each `Checkbox`. This sounds like a good candidate for [snapshot testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing). The idea here is you setup your props, run the test which will create a snapshot file that you commit, and examine the serialized JSON in your snapshot file. The `expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()` assertion will fail if the component output changes, at which point you can either fix the change that broke the test or update the snapshot if its output is correct.

*DisplayTypes.spec.tsx*

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import displayTypes from './displayTypes';

describe('displayTypes', () => {
  it('should check when applicator type is found in user applicator types', () => {
    // arrange
    const props = {
      appTypes: [ ... ],
      changed: () => {},
      isChecked: false,
      userAssignedApplicatorTypes: [ ... ]
    };

    // act
    const tree = renderer
      .create(<displayType {...props}></displayType>)
      .toJSON();

    // assert
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
}
```